# Cmd process not accepting command?

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to read the output of the command with the following argument.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
processStartInfo.Arguments = "nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv";
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Debug.Write("Test1 \n"); // it prints
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
using (StreamReader streamReader = process.StandardOutput)
{
    Debug.Write("Test2 \n"); // it prints
    output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    Debug.Write("Test3 \n"); // it doesn t print
}

String[] substrings = output.Split(delimiter2);
```

I should mention that the command is valid if i run it manually.

Comment: It is not valid if run manually, you are only running half your command manually. Type `cmd /?`. Also there is no reason to be using CMD in the first place.

Comment: @Mark If i change the argument to  `processStartInfo.Arguments = "CMD /C nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv";` i get " 'nvidia-smi' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Could you be more specific on what i should change in order for it to return the output that i get when i run the argument directly into cmd?

Comment: You didnt get what mark meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("nvidia-smi");
processStartInfo.Arguments = "--query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv";
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Firstly - cmd.exe is not the binary you want to launch, because it doesnt have nvidia command line arguments. You actually want to launch - nvidia-smi.

You may face exceptions like File Not Found if nvidia-smi is not in your PATH variable. I nthat case you will have to use FULL PATH to the binary.

Updated: 25/02/2020

The following works for me:
[image]

Also note that my compilation targets 64 bit:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant but I updated this line as follows `ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\nvidia-smi");`. Now, when trying to start the process I get this error " Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll".

Comment: That is because nvidia-smi is a 64 bit binary. Change your project to build to x64 rather than AnyCPU.

Comment: I get the exact same error when building to x64. Could you please help me?

Comment: Try adding .exe to the binary name